# How to stop empty class taking up space before filled by Javascript

Tags: html, css

I am using Javascript to build a check out calculator and I am inputing the data like this:

```
<p class="car-rent-class-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-pickupdropoff-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-coverage-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-age-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-dropfee-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-adddriver-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-roadside-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-afterhours-info h6 pb-1"></p>
<p class="car-rent-tax-info h6 pb-1">Tax Included</p>
<h2 class="car-rent-price-total h1 t600"></h2>
```

With the script looking like this:

```
carpricetotal = $( ".car-rent-price-total" );
carpricetotal.html("$"+generateBillMath(DaysBetween(start_date,end_date),dayprice, weeklyprice, monthlyprice, car_class, pickup_loc, dropoff_loc, coveragec));
```

The only issue is that unless all the fields are filled there can be some pretty ugly gaps, here is a screenshot for example:

[image]

What is a good way of preventing that ugly vertical spacing?

Comment: Show us the CSS, please.

Comment: I imagine there is some margin causing it to take up space.  Perhaps as long as you're populating it w/ jQuery you can also add a class called `.populated`-- that way you could give it _no_ margin unless it has the `.populated` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra spacing is probably caused by the `margin` for `<p>`.

You can use the `:empty` CSS pseudo-selector to remove margin when there is no content. [More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

```css
.pb {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.pb:empty,
p:empty {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<p></p>

<div class="pb"></div>

Hello
```

Comment: This did a lot to help solve my problem, however - the gaps are still there, but much more minor now. Any more advice?

Comment: @tony depends on your structure as it's not clear what is causing the issue.  maybe you need to make `padding:0px;` as well. Try the edited code. Also, using the `hide()` isn't ideal as you would end up having to hide many elements.

Comment: Nope, still there.

Comment: can you provide sample code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Got it! I had to label it !important

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class in css to

```
display: none;
```

that way no space will be allocated to the element. And then you can show it, after adding content like this in jQuery:

```
carpricetotal = $( ".car-rent-price-total" );
carpricetotal.html("$"+generateBillMath(DaysBetween(start_date,end_date),dayprice, weeklyprice, monthlyprice, car_class, pickup_loc, dropoff_loc, coveragec));
carpricetotal.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have html elements that are empty if the corresponding field isn't filled out. But those are all block-level elements that have default styles, including top and bottom margin.

You can add a class to all the empty ones to hide them. Or if you're using jQuery (which it looks like you are), you can use `hide`:

```
// do this for each p or header that doesn't have input data
$( ".car-rent-price-total" ).hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using bootstrap based on some of the classes you are using. `<p>` by default adds a margin on top and at the bottom.

You can add the `m{side}-{size}`, where size are numbers from 0 to 5. This is from [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/#notation)

Where {side}:

- t - top
- b - bottom
- l - left
- r - right
- x - top and bottom
- y - left and right

Where {size}:

- 0 - 0rem
- 1 - 0.25rem
- 2 - 0.5rem
- 3 - 1rem
- 4 - 1.5rem
- 5 - 3rem

So you can modify your code to add `mx-0` to remove the 'gaps' between paragraphs like so:

```
<p class="car-rent-class-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-pickupdropoff-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-coverage-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-age-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-dropfee-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-adddriver-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-roadside-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-afterhours-info h6 pb-1 mx-0"></p>
<p class="car-rent-tax-info h6 pb-1 mx-0">Tax Included</p>
<h2 class="car-rent-price-total h1 t600 mx-0"></h2>
```